# International and Irish phone number form validation using jQuery

Tags: jquery, forms, validation

Hi I am working on a jQuery form for work at the moment. It is all brand new to me and have so far managed to get the form working and have most of the validation done and working but I'm having trouble figuring out exactly how to implement validation for the phone input.

The form has 2 sections and onClick of the second submit.  I need the "phone" field to check and validate that a correct phone number has been entered.  I also would like it to have the same shake effect as the rest of the input fields if there is an error!

I found some code online and have inserted it here in the the code for the second section but like I said I am brand new to this so am fully aware that a) this code probably wont work and b) its probably not even in the right place!

if anyone can take a bit of time to explain exactly how I should implement this and tell me exactly where and how I should be placing the code it would be greatly appreciated.

```
    $(function(){
    //original field values
    var field_values = {
            //id        :  value
            'url'       : 'url',
            'yourname'  : 'yourname',
            'email'     : 'email',
            'phone'     : 'phone'
    };

        var url =$("input#url").val();
        var yourname =$("input#yourname").val();
        var email =$("input#email").val();
        var phone =$("input#phone").val();


    //inputfocus
    $('input#url').inputfocus({ value: field_values['url'] });
    $('input#yourname').inputfocus({ value: field_values['yourname'] });
    $('input#email').inputfocus({ value: field_values['email'] }); 
    $('input#phone').inputfocus({ value: field_values['phone'] });



    //reset progress bar
    $('#progress').css('width','0');
    $('#progress_text').html('0% Complete');

    //first_step
    $('form').submit(function(){ return false; });
    $('#submit_first').click(function(){
        //remove classes
        $('#first_step input').removeClass('error').removeClass('valid');

        //ckeck if inputs aren't empty
        var fields = $('#first_step input[type=text]');
        var error = 0;
        fields.each(function(){
            var value = $(this).val();
            if( value.length<12 || value==field_values[$(this).attr('id')] ) {
                $(this).addClass('error');
                $(this).effect("shake", { times:3 }, 50);

                error++;
            } else {
                $(this).addClass('valid');
            }
        });        

        if(!error) {
            if( $('#password').val() != $('#cpassword').val() ) {
                    $('#first_step input[type=password]').each(function(){
                        $(this).removeClass('valid').addClass('error');
                        $(this).effect("shake", { times:3 }, 50);
                    });

                    return false;
            } else {   
                //update progress bar
                $('#progress_text').html('33% Complete');
                $('#progress').css('width','113px');

                //slide steps
                $('#first_step').slideUp();
                $('#second_step').slideDown();     
            }               
        } else return false;
    });

    //second section
    $('#submit_second').click(function(){
        //remove classes
        $('#second_step input').removeClass('error').removeClass('valid');

        var emailPattern = /^[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$/;  
        var fields = $('#second_step input[type=text]');
        var error = 0;
        fields.each(function(){
            var value = $(this).val();
            if( value.length<1 || value==field_values[$(this).attr('id')] || ( $(this).attr('id')=='email' && !emailPattern.test(value) ) ) {
                $(this).addClass('error');
                $(this).effect("shake", { times:3 }, 50);

                error++;
            } else {
                $(this).addClass('valid');
            }


        function validatePhone(phone) {
        var a = document.getElementById(phone).value;
        var filter = /^[0-9-+]+$/;
            if (filter.test(a)) {
                return true;
            }
            else {
                return false;
            }
        }

        $('#phone').blur(function(e) {
            if (validatePhone('txtPhone')) {
                $('#spnPhoneStatus').html('Valid');
                $('#spnPhoneStatus').css('color', 'green');
            }
            else {
                $('#spnPhoneStatus').html('Invalid');
            $('#spnPhoneStatus').css('color', 'red');
            }
        });

     });

        if(!error) {
                //update progress bar
                $('#progress_text').html('66% Complete');
                $('#progress').css('width','226px');

                //slide steps
                $('#second_step').slideUp();
                $('#fourth_step').slideDown();     
        } else return false;

    });


    $('#submit_second').click(function(){
        //update progress bar
        $('#progress_text').html('100% Complete');
        $('#progress').css('width','339px');

        //prepare the fourth step
        var fields = new Array(
            $('#url').val(),
            $('#yourname').val(),
            $('#email').val(),
            $('#phone').val()

        );
        var tr = $('#fourth_step tr');
        tr.each(function(){
            //alert( fields[$(this).index()] )
            $(this).children('td:nth-child(2)').html(fields[$(this).index()]);
        });

        //slide steps
        $('#third_step').slideUp();
        $('#fourth_step').slideDown();            
    });


    $('#submit_fourth').click(function(){

        url =$("input#url").val();
        yourname =$("input#yourname").val();
        email =$("input#email").val();
        phone =$("input#phone").val();

        //send information to server
        var dataString = 'url='+ url + '&yourname=' + yourname + '&email=' + email + '&phone=' + phone;  



        alert (dataString);//return false;  
            $.ajax({  
                type: "POST",  
                url: "http://clients.socialnetworkingsolutions.com/infobox/contact/",  
                data: "url="+url+"&yourname="+yourname+"&email="+email+'&phone=' + phone,
                cache: false,
                success: function(data) {  
                    console.log("form submitted");
                    alert("success");
                }
                });  
        return false;

   });


    //back button
    $('.back').click(function(){
        var container = $(this).parent('div'),
        previous  = container.prev();

        switch(previous.attr('id')) {
            case 'first_step' : $('#progress_text').html('0% Complete');
                  $('#progress').css('width','0px');
                       break;
            case 'second_step': $('#progress_text').html('33% Complete');
                  $('#progress').css('width','113px');
                       break;

            case 'third_step' : $('#progress_text').html('66% Complete');
                  $('#progress').css('width','226px');
                       break;

        default: break;
    }

    $(container).slideUp();
    $(previous).slideDown();
});


});
```

Comment: Could you link to the code you found online?

Comment: http://jquerybyexample.blogspot.com/2012/05/validate-phone-numbers-using-jquery.html 

This is the code i found for validating the phone input! Not sure how to implement it though or if ti will even work??

Comment: Also here is the link to the orginal tutorial i found for creating the form. http://webexpedition18.com/articles/how-to-create-a-multi-step-signup-form-with-css3-and-jquery/ I have alterd it to fit my needs so basically now in the second section i have added an input for a phone number and am unsure where precisely the new validation code will go or what exactly i need? Everything i have seen online seems like a lot of code for what i imagine would be a simple enough task using jQuery?

Comment: We won't write your code for you, sorry.  If you encounter errors, then we can help.  I'd suggest trying something, and then posting here (with the error) if it doesn't work.

Comment: Ok so heres what ive tried then, after looking at some other answers here i've given up on the idea of trying to use unobtrusive javascript in the head of the actual html page and tried something with the jquery instead: